# Organizing images in the bootstrap grid layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hi guys I need help in organizing a group of images using the bootstrap grid layout.
In the image there is the result I want reach: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuJud.png

My code produces this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDa2Z.png

The position of the images is wrong, can you help me watching my code?

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row game-group-titles">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <h4>GIOCHI PREFERITI</h4>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 giocogrosso">
          <img src="../lggioco.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccoloo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccolo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccoloo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccolo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

      <h4>CURRENTLY PLAYING</h4>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 giocogrosso">
          <img src="../lggioco.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccoloo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccolo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccoloo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 giocopiccolo">
          <img src="../giocoo.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you are not applying any margins or padding to your images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for

```css
   
.row {
  background: blue;
  max-width: 410px;
}
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;

  > .col, > [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>GIOCHI PREFERITI</h4>
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12 giocogrosso">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/410x190" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 giocopiccoloo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/205x95" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 giocopiccoloo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/205x95" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 giocopiccoloo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/205x95" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 giocopiccolo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/205x95" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```